# How to locate nearby friends using Map Kit Framework

Tags: xcode, ios5, mapkit

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on how to use the MapKit Framework to enable users to see nearby friends/users on a map? I'm working on an app that resembles the Grindr/Blendr functionality only with a completely different purpose...

Answer (score 0):

There are several good tutorials on how to use the map kit framework in general.
Here's a [link](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/804_Introduction_to_MapKit_Framework_for_iPhone_Development.aspx) to something that will get you started.

If you are interested in a framework that will create the map and add the nearby users to it (which is not a built-in feature in the map kit framework. You have to get these users' locations and add them yourself), you should take a look at [Scringo](http://www.scringo.com)